# MongoDb CSharp driver: Select rows where fieldX in set (val1,val2,val3)

Tags: c#, mongodb

```
var database = new MongoClient("mongodb://192.168.3.122").GetDatabase("TestDb");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Post>("Post");
var res = collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Id.In(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 })).Select(y => y).ToList(); //error here
foreach (var post in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine(post.Id + " " + post.Code);
}
```

I want results similar to this SQL query:

```
Select * From Post Where Id In(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var Ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3};
var res = collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => Ids.Contains(x.Id)).Select(y => y).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `In` filter like this:

```
var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.In(f=> f.Id, new []{ 1, 2, 3 });
```

And get your expected result:

```
// As an Async way
var res = collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().Result;
```

```
// As a Sync way
var res = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```